# Добавить возможность звонить

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api, google-maps

Добавил маркер на карту вместе с некоторым информативным окном.

```
Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(47.045029, 28.861427))
            .title("Marker")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
            .snippet("Population: 4,137,400"));
```

Реализовал в InfoWindow при нажатии кнопку на которую можно нажимать. Как можно добавить возможность звонить по её нажатию на определенный номер(для каждого маркера свой номер)?

Класс Map:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    //final MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(map);
    MapWrapperLayout mapWrapperLayout = (MapWrapperLayout) findViewById(R.id.map_relative_layout);
    //final GoogleMap map = mapFragment.getMap();
    // MapWrapperLayout initialization
    // 39 - default marker height
    // 20 - offset between the default InfoWindow bottom edge and it's content bottom edge
    mapWrapperLayout.init(map, getPixelsFromDp(this, 39 + 20));

    // We want to reuse the info window for all the markers,
    // so let's create only one class member instance
    this.infoWindow = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window, null);
    this.infoTitle = (TextView) infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.title);
    this.infoSnippet = (TextView) infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.snippet);
    this.infoButton = (Button) infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.button);

    // Setting custom OnTouchListener which deals with the pressed state
    // so it shows up
    this.infoButtonListener = new OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener(infoButton,
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_but_green_sel), //btn_default_normal_holo_light
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_but_red_sel)) //btn_default_pressed_holo_light
        {
           @Override
           protected void onClickConfirmed(View v, Marker marker) {
               // Here we can perform some action triggered after clicking the button
               Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, marker.getTitle() + "'s button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
        };
    this.infoButton.setOnTouchListener(infoButtonListener);


    map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                // Setting up the infoWindow with current's marker info
                infoTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
                infoSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());
                infoButtonListener.setMarker(marker);

                mapWrapperLayout.setMarkerWithInfoWindow(marker, infoWindow);
                return infoWindow;
            }
        });

    Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(47.045029, 28.861427))
                .title("Marker")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
                .snippet("Population: 4,137,400"));

    Marker marker2 = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(47.000327, 28.867950))
                .title("Marker")
                .snippet("Population: 4,137,400"))

    builder.include(marker.getPosition());
    builder.include(marker2.getPosition());

    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

    int padding = 150; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
    CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
    map.moveCamera(cu);
}
```

Класс OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener:

```
public abstract class OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    private final View view;
    private final Drawable bgDrawableNormal;
    private final Drawable bgDrawablePressed;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    private Marker marker;
    private boolean pressed = false;

    public OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener(View view, Drawable bgDrawableNormal, Drawable bgDrawablePressed) {
        this.view = view;
        this.bgDrawableNormal = bgDrawableNormal;
        this.bgDrawablePressed = bgDrawablePressed;
    }

    public void setMarker(Marker marker) {
        this.marker = marker;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View vv, MotionEvent event) {
        if (0 <= event.getX() && event.getX() <= view.getWidth() && 0 <= event.getY() && event.getY() <= view.getHeight()) {
            switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    startPress();
                    break;

                // We need to delay releasing of the view a little so it shows the
                // pressed state on the screen
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    handler.postDelayed(confirmClickRunnable, 150);
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    endPress();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            // If the touch goes outside of the view's area
            // (like when moving finger out of the pressed button)
            // just release the press
            endPress();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void startPress() {
        if (!pressed) {
            pressed = true;
            handler.removeCallbacks(confirmClickRunnable);
            view.setBackgroundDrawable(bgDrawablePressed);
            if (marker != null)
                marker.showInfoWindow();
        }
    }

    private boolean endPress() {
        if (pressed) {
            this.pressed = false;
            handler.removeCallbacks(confirmClickRunnable);
            view.setBackgroundDrawable(bgDrawableNormal);
            if (marker != null)
                marker.showInfoWindow();
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }

    private final Runnable confirmClickRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (endPress()) {
                onClickConfirmed(view, marker);
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * This is called after a successful click
     */
    protected abstract void onClickConfirmed(View v, Marker marker);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15040761 ?

Comment: @pavlofff отличный ответ, спасибо, но это лишь первая часть вопроса. Как реализовать саму звонилку по нажатию на кнопку в InfoWindow остаётся открытым. Как думаете возможно стоит обновить вопрос?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Касательно создания кликабельного инфо:

> [stackoverflow.com/a/15040761](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15040761) ? – [pavlofff](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177345/pavlofff) [10 фев в 18:16](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/626293/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C#comment876409_626293)

Касательно звонка по клику:

```
Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone)); //phone - переменная, в которой хранится номер телефона
startActivity(call);
```

Это необходимо вставить в метод, выполняемый после клика

**UPD**

Хранить номер телефона можно так:

```
Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(47.045029, 28.861427))
                .title("Marker")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
                .snippet("Population: 4,137,400"));
marker.setTag(phone);
```

А использовать его так:

```
this.infoButtonListener = new OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener(infoButton,
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_but_green_sel), //btn_default_normal_holo_light
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_but_red_sel)) //btn_default_pressed_holo_light
        {
            @Override
            protected void onClickConfirmed(View v, Marker marker) {
                Object tag = marker.getTag();
                if (tag != null){
                    Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                    call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + String.valueOf(tag)));
                    startActivity(call);
                }else{
                    //обработать момент, когда номера нет, необходимо здесь
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: Спасибо, но если я правильно понимаю это общий пример, то есть для всех маркеров, при нажатии будет один и тот же номер. В вопросе было небольшое уточнение по поводу - "для каждого маркера свой номер".

Comment: @Inkognito заместо переменной `phone` используйте свою переменную, в которой хранится номер, именно для этого маркера и тогда звонки будут на разные номера

Comment: Ну я же ваш отрывок кода вставлю в метод где у меня происходит клик, соответственно для каждого клика, будет один и тот же номер. Я не совсм понимаю как мне потом использовать его для каждого окна в отдельности? К примеру есть параметры для маркера где задаю текст/координаты/snippet/icon как сюда возможно запихнуть ещё и номер? извините, но я реально не совсем понимаю конструкцию.

Comment: @Inkognito обновил ответ

Comment: Сделал всё в точности также, но появились следующие ошибки: 
1) Cannot resolve symbol ACTION_DEAL
2) здесь подправил пока следующим образом, но не уверен что так будет лучше `                    call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + String.valueOf(tag)));`

Comment: @Inkognito возможно ACTION_DIAL ?

Comment: @Morozov Да, спасибо, исправил.

Comment: @Inkognito Поправил, теперь должно работать

Comment: @zTrap я бы ещё permissions необходимые добавил, для будущих читателей.

Comment: @Morozov для `ACTION_DIAL` не нужны разрешения

Comment: @zTrap спасибо за ответ, всё получилось, на перспективу вопрос для кнопки отправить email, наверное та же самая операция с intentom только для случая отправки почты?)

Comment: @Inkognito да, так же можно отправлять и почту

Comment: @zTrap получилось отправлять и почту, только с тагами не совсем понятно, по-моему они пересекаются с телефонами)

Comment: @Inkognito посмотри все перегрузки метода `setTag`, одна из них поддерживает несколько тегов

Comment: @zTrap пробую я значит, возможно вы сможете помочь http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/642060/220675