# Мультитаги для маркера

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api

Столкнулся c проблемой добавить несколько тагов для маркера. А именно меня интересует добавление почты/номера телефона.
Для этого решил создать некую модель для использования данной фичи, не знаю на сколько верно, но всё таки:

```
public class MarkerTag {
    private String email;
    private String phoneNumber;

    public MarkerTag() {
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

Далее прошу обратить Ваше внимание на то, как я собственно потом решил добавлять эти таги к моим маркерам:

```
MarkerTag tag = new MarkerTag();
Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(47.045029, 28.861427))
        .title("Marker")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
        .snippet("Population: 4,137,400"));
tag.setPhoneNumber("+37369490007");
tag.setEmail("first@gmail.com");
marker.setTag(tag);

tag = new MarkerTag();
Marker marker2 = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(47.000327, 28.867950))
        .title("Marker")
        .snippet("Population: 4,137,400 test"));
tag.setPhoneNumber("+37369339092");
tag.setEmail("second@gmail.com");
marker.setTag(tag);
```

Ну и собственно два метода которые я реализовал под эти нужды:

```
private void makeCall(Marker marker) {
    Object tag = marker.getTag();
    if (tag != null) {
        Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + String.valueOf(tag)));
        startActivity(call);
    }
}

private void sendEmail(Marker marker) {
    Object tag = marker.getTag();
    if (tag != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text");
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(("email" + String.valueOf(tag))));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        checkAndStart(this, intent, R.string.action_settings);
    }
}
```

Но что я получил в конце, теперь по нажатию на маркер и открытия infoWindow где у меня расположены две кнопки call/sendEmail по нажатию на call из двух маркеров, работает только нажатие и набор на один из номеров и то выдаёт вместо вбитого номера большое количество цифр. А по нажатию на отправить email выбивает ошибку:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.vm.sai, PID: 13283
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker.getTag()' on a null object reference
    at com.vm.sai.activities.MapsActivity.sendEmail(MapsActivity.java:166)
    at com.vm.sai.activities.MapsActivity.-wrap1(MapsActivity.java)
    at com.vm.sai.activities.MapsActivity$2.onClickConfirmed(MapsActivity.java:92)
    at com.vm.sai.utils.OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener$1.run(OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener.java:84)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Неверный номер при звонке

Звонить у вас получается на один и тот же номер потому, что установка телефона в тег выглядит следующим образом:

Создание объекта → заполнение данными → передача ссылки объекта в первый тег → изменение данных в объекте → передача ссылки объекта во второй тег

А должно быть так:

Создание объекта → заполнение данными → передача ссылки объекта в первый тег → **создание нового объекта** → **заполнение данными** → передача ссылки объекта во второй тег

---

В коде это будет выглядеть так:

```
MarkerTag tag = new MarkerTag();
Marker marker = map.addMarker(...);
tag.setEmail("first@gmail.com");
tag.setPhoneNumber("+37369490007");
marker.setTag(tag);

tag = new MarkerTag();
Marker marker2 = map.addMarker(...);
tag.setEmail("second@gmail.com");
tag.setPhoneNumber("+37368750588");
marker2.setTag(tag);
```

---

### NullPointerException

Вся проблема в том, что в какой-то момент вам приходит `marker == null`. А так, как проверки на это у вас нет, то при обращении к методам объекта, который равен `null` выбрасывается `NullPointerException`.

---

В коде это будет выглядеть так:

```
private void makeCall(Marker marker) {
    MarkerTag tag = checkTag(marker);
    if (tag == null) return;
    Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + String.valueOf(tag.getPhoneNumber())));
    startActivity(call);
}

private void sendEmail(Marker marker) {
    MarkerTag tag = checkTag(marker);
    if (tag == null) return;
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{tag.getEmail()})
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text")
                        .setType("message/rfc822"), "Выберите приложение для отправки письма: "));
}

private MarkerTag checkTag(Marker marker){
    if (marker != null && marker.getTag() instanceof MarkerTag){
        return (MarkerTag) marker.getTag();
    }else return null;
}
```

[Что такое NullPointerException и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/511086/205238)

Comment: Не получается каждый раз создавать MarkerTag tag = new MarkerTag();, ну потому что tag будет использоваться каждый раз, поэтому создал tag1 tag2 и т д , но к сожалению ситуацию не изменило(

Comment: @Inkognito Можно обновить код?

Comment: обновил вопрос с новыми проблемами.

Comment: @Inkognito не вижу проверки маркера на `null`

Comment: ну я же в методах проверяю на null

Comment: @Inkognito Перечитайте ответ, у вас проверка тега, а не маркера

Comment: и мне типо ниже делать ещё проверку маркера? как то не выходит пока))

Comment: @Inkognito обновил ответ

Comment: да, спасибо понял теперь что вы имели в виду, ошибку не выдаёт но ситуация по тагам ни к чему не привела(  по-прежнему не хочет выводитькорректный номер по нажатию на отправить почту, ничего вообще не происходит

Comment: Вообщем странная вещица на самом деле, если просто запилить метод, который будет отправлять на определенный email то работает всё круто, если же реализовать метод sendEmail как вы мне подсказали то log выводит tag  == null (